# Regular expression for single place decimal number with either 0 or 5

Tags: regex

What is the regular expression for a decimal number with only one decimal place and either 0 or 5 (whole number of half) and no other.

e.g. **1.0, 3.5, 10.5** and not **1.2, 3.7** e.t.c.

Thank you.

Comment: digits, dot, 0 or 5 : `\d+\.[05]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below,

```
^\d+\.[05]$
```

Make the decimal part as optional to accept also the integer numbers.

```
^\d+(?:\.[05])?$
```

Explanation:

`^` - Asserts that we are at the start.

`\d+` -matches one or more digits.

`\.` - A literal dot.

`[05]` - 0 or 5

`$` - End of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
\d+\.(0|5)\D*
```

You might want to replace `\D*` (anything that is not a number) with something else depending on the format you are going to be searching, like line breaks. Also, you *might* not need to escape the period.